# Raise to the power in shell

Tags: shell, exponential

How do you raise *m* to the power of *n*? I've searched for this everywhere. What I found was that writing `m**n` should work, but it doesn't. I'm using `#!/bin/sh`.

Comment: because `m**n` is a bash feature that is not available in sh

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I would try the calculator bc. See http://www.basicallytech.com/blog/index.php?/archives/23-command-line-calculations-using-bc.html for more details and examples.

eg.

```
$ echo '6^6' | bc
```

Gives 6 to the power 6.

Comment: Awesome! Used to do my own math functions in bash, created a lot of useless ugly code! Thanks! Didn't know about bc.

Comment: if you can spare 40 more megabytes to install it, [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) does the trick and can handle bigger numbers, is faster, and has richer computations. to answer the original question:  `echo 6^6 | gp -q`

Answer (score 33):

Using $n**$m really works indeed.
Maybe you don't use the correct syntax to evaluate a math expression.
Here's how I get the result on Bash:

```
echo $(($n**$m))
```

or

```
echo $[$n**$m]
```

The square brackets here are not meant to be like the test evaluator in the if statement so you can you use them without spaces too. I personally prefer the former syntax with round brackets.

Comment: This question asked for a solution for *shell* which means POSIX shell. Your solution does not work in a POSIX compliant shell like dash but just happens to work in more featureful shells like bash or zsh.

Comment: This is the answer that I was looking for and that I would accept. Thank you @Gianni

Comment: Note that this is limited to integers only - Bash can't handle non-integer arithmetic.  Also, `echo $((n ** n))` will work as well - no need for `$` to expand variables inside the arithmetic expression, `(( ... ))`.

Comment: Careful with this if you're dealing with large numbers. For example, `$((2**100))` gives 0 on my machine. Using `bc` works with larger numbers.

Answer (score 9):

using `bc` is an elegant solution. If you want to do this in bash:

```
$ n=7
$ m=5

$ for ((i=1, pow=n; i<m; i++)); do ((pow *= n)); done
$ echo $pow
16807

$ echo "$n^$m" | bc  # just to verify the answer
16807
```

Comment: In bash you can also use `$((7**5))`.

Comment: well, then. that's even easier.

Answer (score 4):

You might use dc. This

```
dc -e "2 3 ^ p"
```

yields

```
8
```

Comment: this might interest ppl interested in dc https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/124524/30352

Answer (score 1):

My system admin didn't install `dc` so adding to other correct answers, I bet you have not thought of this -

```
a=2
b=3
python -c "print ($a**$b)"
>> 8
```

works in bash/shell.

Answer (score -1):

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "Enter the number to be done"
n=2
read m
let P=( $n**$m )
echo "The answer is $p"
```

---

### ANSWER

```
Enter the number to be done
3
The answer is 8
```